# How implement the following chart in latest google chart api?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Any ideas how to implement the x and y values on the same row ?

Currently im up to this and have quite big problem to set the x and y on two rows 1 under other.

```
var options = {
    isStacked:true,
    hAxis: {
        gridlines: {
            color: '#fff',
            count: 8
        },
        showTextEvery: 1,
        title: 'КМ/Ч'
    },
    vAxis: {
        gridlines: {
            color: '#fff',
            count: 8
        },
        minorGridlines: {
            color: 'red'
        },
        viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
        viewWindow: {
            max: 100
        },
        title: 'ЧАС'
    },
    axisTitlesPosition: 'out',
    axes: {
        y: {
            0: { side: 'top'}
        }
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'none'
    },
    annotations: {
    },
    backgroundColor: {
        stroke: '#fff',
        fill: '#fff',
        strokeWidth: 0
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/1645/

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to plot both values from each row in the array.

The problem is the `LineChart` is looking for some sort of label in the first column to use on the h-axis.

Here, I use a view to create a duplicate column for the row labels...

```js
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

    data.addRows([
        [1, 10],  [2, 23],  [3, 17],  [4, 18],  [5, 9], [11, 35],
        [6, 11],  [7, 27],  [8, 33],  [9, 40],  [10, 32], [11, 35],
        [12, 30], [13, 40], [14, 42], [15, 47], [16, 44], [17, 48],
        [18, 52], [19, 54], [20, 42], [21, 55], [22, 56], [23, 57],
        [24, 60], [25, 50], [26, 52], [27, 51], [28, 49], [29, 53],
        [30, 55], [31, 60], [32, 61], [33, 59], [34, 62], [35, 65],
        [36, 62], [37, 58], [38, 55], [39, 61], [40, 64], [41, 65],
        [42, 63], [43, 66], [44, 67], [45, 69], [46, 69], [47, 70],
        [48, 72], [49, 68], [50, 66], [51, 65], [52, 67], [53, 70],
        [54, 71], [55, 72], [56, 73], [57, 75], [58, 70], [59, 68],
        [60, 64], [61, 60], [62, 65], [63, 67], [64, 68], [65, 69],
        [66, 70], [67, 72], [68, 75], [69, 80]
    ]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([{calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 0, type: "string"},0,1]);
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(view, {});
}

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```